# Arbitrary value in Excel within formula

Tags: excel

How do I get an 'x', as in a symbol for an arbitrary value, within a formula (using Excel 2013)?

I would like my formula, in cell B1, to look something like: `If(A1>=x,5; ROUND.UP(A1; 0); A1)`

The result in cell B1 should then be:

- If A1 = 1,5, then B1 should be 2.
- If A1 = 9,8, then B1 should be 10.
- If A1 = 13,2, then B1 should be 13,2.

If there is no wildcard for a number, do you have a suggestion as to how I might arrive at the right results? The range of values for x is 0-50, I believe.

Best,
Asger

Comment: To be clear, that there be an actual 'x' within the formular in B2 matters not.What matters is that the formular in B2 be able to provide the result of the formular wherein x is placed as a placeholder for an arbitrary value.

Comment: Here's an example: A1 is the sum of the number of employees in a department divided by some value. 100/15, say. A2-An are sums of other departments. B1-Bn should then round up the sum of the respective A column in any case the value is equal to or higher than x,5 [something point five], e.g., 1,5, 2,7, 13,9 etc. In any case where the sum is not above the x,5 threshold, it should simply provide the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in cell B1:

```
    =IF(MOD(A1,1)<0.5,A1,ROUND(A1,0))
```

`MOD()` will return the digits after the comma, regardless of the value of the number in A1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the letter "x" into your formula you can use a named range ... i.e. go to a cell and name it ***X*** (allthough I recommend to use more meaningfull names as range names ... e.g. "Threshold_X")

the "x,5" may need to be converted into ***X + 0.5*** (if my understanding is correct)

Comment: Minor addendum that most will already realize; this method may also be accomplished without using a named range. Absolute reference will do the same trick, but would be more complicated to use if the cell is "far away" in any sense of the phrase.